# Firebase crash while using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm facing a very weird issue. I just upgraded my play-services dependencies from version **10.0.1** to **10.2.0**

I'm using these now:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.0'
```

Now my app crashes every time I receiver a push notification. Notification is displayed and right after that I get a dialog saying that my app stopped working.

**Crash LOG**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
               Process: com.avantcar.a2go, PID: 581
               java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzaaj()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzg; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.zzg' appears in /data/app/com.avantcar.a2go-1/base.apk:classes69.dex)
               at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzF(Unknown Source)
               at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3010)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(ActivityThread.java)
               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1442)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It seems like it's crashing because of something related to FCM, but I am not using FCM in my app yet. I'm still using GCM.

Comment: Which version of Android are you running the app on?

Comment: @JoaoSousa 6.0 Build number MPA44G

Comment: Do you import any of the Firebase libraries? Like firebase-messaging, or firebase-core. If you do, you need to update those to 10.2.0 as well.

Comment: No, I do use Smooch though, which apparently also supports FCM, but I commented out all of Smooch code, but it still crashes. I updated every possible library to 10.2.0

Comment: Well try importing them then. You shouldn't really use GCM anyway. It looks like something internally is trying to call a method via reflection only available through FCM, so add `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'` and `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'` to your app.gradle

Comment: Thing is that I wasn't planning on migrating to FCM just yet. As far as I understand, migrating to FCM requires generating new API keys, also some work on backend etc. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: You're not wrong. Some backend work is needed, although it is very straightforward.

Comment: can you print and add to the question the list of app dependencies?
./gradlew app:dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and it was because I was using a different version for messaging, so **try to use the same version on all firebase related dependencies**.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to accept the answer. This is not exactly what was my problem, but it brought me to the solution. I was indeed using incompatible Firebase versions.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to please check your Android API level.

As mentioned in [Google APIs for Android - Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_v102), updating your Google Play Services to 10.2 will require a minimum Android API level of 14.

Here are additional articles/SO post that will also help:

- [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html?hl=be)
- [Google Play Services Release Notes are Available for the 10.2 Update — Bye Gingerbread!](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-services-release-notes-are-available-for-the-10-2-update-bye-gingerbread/)
- [Android Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) token generation crash after Firebase-related Google Play Services update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37337393/android-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-token-generation-crash-after-firebase-relat)

Answer (score 0):

using google play services 10.2.0 and the same for firebase messaging worked for me.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this configuration

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.0'
```

fixes multi dupex gradle compilation error on AndroidStudio 2.3.3.