# GCM Error - googleCloudMessaging.register

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, sap-fiori, gcmlistenerservice

I have the problem that the android application says. "The application xxxx Sorry stopped" to work with the push notificaction, when performing the debugger that happens when it passes:

method 1

```
InstanceID InstanceId = InstanceID.getInstance (context);

 token = instanceID.getToken (key_id.toString ()

GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE); getToken error,
```

method 2

Both an the same mistake

```
 if (googleCloudMessaging == null) {
googleCloudMessaging = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    token = googleCloudMessaging.register(key_id);
```

note that the token is generated but the application is closed, error:

```
"The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir (android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but was found to be Instead of direct type (declaration of 'java.lang .reflect.ArtMethod 'appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)"
```

I am using android studio, for
cdvCompileSdkVersion = android-22
cdvBuildToolsVersion = 22.0.1

Error:

```
"FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process:  PID: 11989
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzde(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService.zzn(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceIDListenerService.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2924)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)"
```

What could be the problem?

Regards,

Comment: Which support libraries your are using?.....try updating your support libraries

Comment: GCM was just deprecated - Firebase Cloud Messaging is the new service. FCM manages registering for you and getting the token is easier too. You are strongly recommended to implement FCM instead. Here is a link how to migrate from GCM: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm

Comment: can we not resolve it with gcm if so how?

Answer (score 5):

Google has updated on their release note that this issue is fixed, you just have to update the version to 9.0.2

Here is the release note: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are experiencing is due to an incompatibility between
`play-services / firebase sdk v9.0.0` and  `com.android.support:appcompat-v7 >= 24`
It's possible that you are not depending directly from appcompat-v7 >= 24 but some other dependencies are configured to use the most updated appcompat available.

To fix this issue we just released `play-services / firebase sdk` version **9.0.1**
This minor release should fix the incompatibility with appcompat-v7 !

Comment: I can confirm that this incompatibility exists for Google Play Services v8.4.0 as well.  Speculation: appcompat-v7 >= 24 and Google Play Services < v9.0.1 are incompatible.

Comment: I'm getting this error `Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.` my google service plugin `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` and i have `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` at the end of file. and i have appcompat dependency as `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'`

Answer (score 1):

I also facing same error.

**SOLUTION**

Just paste this in your gradle file

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        }
    }
```

This issue is that you have dependencies that include old versions of the support library. [CHECK THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37322365/android-urbanairship-crash-in-takeoff)

Here is my gradle file check this

**gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'hwindi'
            keyPassword '123456'
            storeFile file('D:/Company Projects/Hwindi/Project 2/Play_KeyStore/HwindiKeyStore.jks')
            storePassword '123456'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hwindiapp.passenger"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/mips/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_imgproc.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioDecider.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_core.so'
        exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.so'
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
            force 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
            force 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.mukesh:permissions:1.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have read, `java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist` error, which you encountered after migrating a GCM Client App for Android to Firebase Cloud Messaging, were also encountered by many developers after adding the dependency for Crash Reporting to project-level `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
```

So, if you happen to use Firebase Crash Reporting, you must ensure that crash reporting is multi-process safe. Otherwise, it may cause concurrency issues as stated in [Report Crashes - Known Issues](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android#known-issues).

One probable solution that I found is to set Android context and enable Offline Persistence, wherein you enable it via the FirebaseDatabase object in your MainActivity:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Sample solution in MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  if (!FirebaseApp.getApps(this).isEmpty()) {
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

This SO post - [java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37346363/java-lang-illegalstateexception-firebaseapp-with-name-default) helped with my searches. I hope that will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this problem is solved on **v9.0.2**. Just update Google Play Service library.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

After updating, another error can occur: **finished with non-zero exit value 2**
Solution for this one is here: [Java finished with non-zero exit value 2 - Android Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756188/java-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2-android-gradle)

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by using below code. Just updated

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
.
.
.
dependencies
{
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0"
}
```

This solved my GCM error.